# run a part of a script in other terminal

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

I need to run a part of a script in other terminal windows. For example:

```
# first echo run in terminal window 1
echo "This echo command print in window 1"
# first echo run in terminal window 2
echo "This echo command print in window 2"
# first echo run in terminal window 3
echo "This echo command print in window 3"
```

Please answer with example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
xterm -e 'echo "This echo command print in window 1"'
```

will start an Xterm window and tell it to execute that command.

Replace `xterm` with the actual terminal program you're using (e.g. `gnome-terminal`). It may also use different syntax for providing a command to execute, so check its documentation for the correct syntax.